# Were the ending triggers for Silent Hill: Shattered Memories ever definitively discovered?

Tags: silent-hill-shattered-memories

Particularly with regards to the Wicked and Weak ending, there seems to be a lot of confusion surrounding what triggers them. For example, [here's one YouTuber](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6JUH6Jrl9GQ) speaking in depth regarding their frustration. Of note, this video was released in 2015, long after the game was released. Apparently, despite deep research, they couldn't find a reliable way to trigger specific endings.

Were the precise triggers for the game's several endings ever discovered with a high degree of certainty? The most reliable source would be from decompiling the game, but I'm happy to see weaker evidence.

Answer (score 3):

Hi everytime I was playing Silent Hill Shattered Memoreies I used this **guide to achive required ending** for example on this page :

- https://shshatteredmemories.com/shattered-memories-endings/

For exmaple Wicked & Weak ending:

**What happens:** Cheryl catches Dahlia’s verbal and physical abuse of Harry on camera.

**How to get it:** *During your time in Silent Hill be as selfish and stand offish as possible and act like you can’t be bothered with anyone or anything. This means not taking the time to look at the sexual and drug references and ignore phone calls whenever possible. When in a conversation with any of the characters refuse to look them in the eye.*

Some good ways to show you are snob and unlikeable during the game:

- In the initial questionare answer “no” to “I always listen to other people’s feelings” and “I make friends easily”
- In the initial questionare answer “yes” to “I prefer abstract ideas” and “Working to a plan or schedule is best”
- Enter Clear Picture
- During the second therapy session say “yes” to being a private person and for people to get to know you. But say “no” to spending time with friends over family.
- In the third therapy session make sure to say you were a bully in highschool
- Fill your perfect school day with academic classes only
- Go through the Planetarium
- Fail to get all the school pictures taken
- When following Lisa and Michelle go off course so they stop talking and tell you to hurry up
- Watch Lisa change, if she’s angry instead of flattered it’s a good sign.
- Give Lisa the wrong color pill
- In the fifth therapy session place Celestine as the most guilty for her death.
- In the seventh therapy session claim all the abstract images are non sexual.

**If you are on the right track for this ending Harry will be wearing a green polo and brown pea-coat.**

There are written few hints for triggers what you need to do to achive ending you want.
Also I was using **this document written by Marie Roberts from 2012 where are described a lot of triggers and how to achive defferent endings:**

- https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/ps2/959241-silent-hill-shattered-memories/faqs/65318